# Uncaught TypeError: e.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, datatables

Tengo una tabla para mostrar algunos datos entre ellos lo gramos y kilos que pesa un material, que lo hago haciendo una conversión al dar clic en gramos o kilos y la cantidad de tanques que necesito para la cantidad de material, este lo solicito mediante un input,  lo que sucede es que al dar clic en la conversión de gramos a kilos o en el input genera el error

> Uncaught TypeError: e.push is not a function

aunque sigue funcionando.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  tablePesaje = $('#tablePesaje').dataTable({
    ajax: {
      url: `../../api/materiasp/${referencia}`,
      dataSrc: ''
    },
    paging: false,
    info: false,
    searching: false,
    sorting: false,
    
    columns: [
      {
        title: 'Referencia',
        data: 'referencia', className: 'uniqueClassName'
      },
      {
        title: 'Materia Prima',
        data: 'alias', className: 'uniqueClassName'
      },
      {
        title: 'Peso (<a href="javascript:cambioConversion();" class="conversion_weight">g</a>)',
        className: 'conversion_weight_column',
        data: 'porcentaje', className: 'uniqueClassName',
        render: (data, type, row) => {
          if (flagWeight) {
            return (data * batch.tamano_lote).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
          } else { 
            return (data * batch.tamano_lote/ 1000).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
          }
        },
      },
      {
        title: '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Notanques" placeholder="Tanques" style="width:52px; text-align:center" onkeydown="calcularxNoTanques();">',
        data: 'porcentaje', className: 'uniqueClassName',
        render: (data, type, row) => {
          let tanque = $('#Notanques').val();
          if (flagWeight && tanque!='') {
            return (data * batch.tamano_lote * $('#Notanques').val()).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
          } else {
            return (data * batch.tamano_lote / 1000 / $('#Notanques').val()).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
          }
        },
      },
      {
        title: 'Impresión',
        defaultContent: '<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#imprimirEtiquetas"><i class="large material-icons">print</i></a>', className: 'uniqueClassName'
      }
    ],
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      $.extend( true, {}, {
        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
        text: 'Exportar PDF',
        title: 'Formula Producto ' + batch.referencia,
        exportOptions: {
          columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ]
        }
      })
    ]
  });
});
```

Comment: Y en todo el códig que subes, ¿donde está `e` y la llamada a `push`?

Comment: Hola Mauricio, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, te cuento que eso es lo raro, parece como si fuera de datatables porque estoy utilizando algo mal, pero no es de mi codigo. datatables.min.js:95 Uncaught TypeError: e.push is not a function
    at Za (datatables.min.js:95)
    at datatables.min.js:95
    at HTMLTableCellElement.<anonymous> (datatables.min.js:101)
    at HTMLTableCellElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLTableCellElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)

Comment: @SergioEduardoVelandiaObando tienes que echarle un ojo a los parametros. Lo que está sucediendo es que el script está esperando un array donde no lo hay, `e` seguramente es una variable minimizada. Lo que te recomendaría es que vayas agregando los parametros de a poco hasta que veas en cual está fallando.